# Django change object names in proxy model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a many to many field where Django creates the 'through' table automatically

```
roomextra = models.ManyToManyField(
    to='hotel.RoomExtra',
    related_name='room_extra',
    verbose_name='room extra',
)
```

This is part of a Room class. Both the Room class and RoomExtra class have methods

```
def __str__
```

To define their object name. A proxy model was introduced to change some text on the Django admin for the through table created by Django:

```
class RoomRoomExtraProxy(Room.roomextra.through):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.room.name + ' // ' + self.roomextra.name
```

However, when you try and delete a room with a room extra you get the following on the 'Are you sure?' page:

```
Summary

 - Rooms: 1
 - Room-roomextra relationships: 1

Objects

 - Room: 1
 - Room-roomextra relationship: Room_roomextra object (8)
```

How do I override 'Room-roomextra' and 'Room_roomextra object (8)' so that they are more user friendly?